# UISegmentedControl not firing event on programatically added segments

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm creating a UISegementedControl in code, and using the target/action to do some custom animation of the control.  The problem is that when tapping the newly added segment, no event is fired. Here's the setup code for the UISegmented Control:

```
_controlView = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"$100"]];
[_controlView addTarget:self action:@selector(controlViewTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And the action handler:

```
-(void)controlViewTapped:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Control was tapped: %@", sender);
    if (!_isExpanded) {
        _isExpanded = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [_controlView setTitle:self.expandedText forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [_controlView insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Size 10" atIndex:1 animated:YES];
            [_controlView setContentOffset:_offset forSegmentAtIndex:1];
            [_controlView setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        }];
    } else {
        _isExpanded = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [_controlView setTitle:self.collapsedText forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [_controlView removeSegmentAtIndex:1 animated:YES];
        }];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

When the view is expanded, no event is fired when tapping on the second segment.  I've tried removing and re-adding the target, using a tap gesture recognizer and removing/re-adding it to no avail.  Any suggestions?